# How can I locate, access and modify files of my mounted extenal Hard Drive using Terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal

Basically,  I am using Fedora37 OS so,
what are the Commands for accessing external hard drive files using terminal in Fedora?

I want to copy all files of my external Hard Drive, how can I locate my drive in terminal, moreover which commands will I use to cut or copy existing files from and to external hard drive.
I already tried `ls` in `home` and `root` directory but does not work.

Answer (score 1):

By your question, I am guessing you're new to the Linux command line. I'm not shaming you by the way, it is tricky to get into. I'll try to help you out as much as I can.

When you plugin a hard drive to Linux, you'll need to mount it so you can access its' contents. You can use the `mount` program for this. After mounting, you can then explore that filesystem with `ls` or `cd` and copy/move files with `cp`/`mv`. You can also see the usage and mount points of all mounted partitions with `df -h`.

For any of these programs, you can always call on the man page by using `man <program>`. For example, `man mount` would open the manual for the mount program.

Since a step-by-step has been written a hundred times for this exact question, I'll just paste a link to a nice guide. If you have any questions, however, don't hesitate to ask. https://www.howtogeek.com/414634/how-to-mount-and-unmount-storage-devices-from-the-linux-terminal/

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```bash
# List your disks to find the name of your external drive
lsblk

# Create a directory to mount it to 
mkdir /media/my-external-drive
 
# Mount your disk (lets say its called "sda")  
sudo mount /dev/sda /media/my-external-drive

# Create a folder (or whatever you want..)  
mkdir ~/target-folder

# Copy you files from the drive to your target folder
cp /media/my-external-drive/* ~/target-folder/
```